# How can I use gulp in a docker container, so the front-end build process takes place in a container?

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose, dockerfile, assets

I have set up a development environment with docker-compose. I use gulp to manage my front end build process, which still runs on the host machine, rather than the container. How can I go about running this in a docker container?

This is for a development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a great idea. You should not have your dev dependencies in the container. You should do the build on your build slave (using Jenkins or something) and then copy the generated build files into the Docker web server container that will serve them up.

Look here - https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/your-angular-apps-as-docker-containers-471f570a7f2

Comment: I should have mentioned in the original question, this is for a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

So I do something similar to what you are trying to achieve (I am building a MERN stack type) app which builds my client (usually running on host machine) that then after build copies it over to my node/express server to create an image...
So you could create a Dockerfile to do this and then tie that in to your Docker-Compose? I am assuming you only want to build at set stages?

Where I have yarn build is essentially where you would run gulp......

```
FROM node:10 as build-deps
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY client/package.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY client ./
RUN yarn build

FROM node:10
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/client
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/build /usr/src/app/client
COPY server/. /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3050
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```